# Dynamically create types : Emit vs Compilation performance

Tags: c#, dynamic-compilation

**EDIT** (TLDR), my question is : ***why is there a huge gap between the two methods (a factor of 10)***.

There are (I think) two ways of creating types dynamically : with Emit, and from source code at runtime. I wanted to benchmark the two, and I found that compilation from source code is 10 times faster. Is that Normal? I feel i'm doing something wrong.

Here I define the number of types I'm creating (4000).

```
static int limit = 4000;
```

This is the code that allows me to create 4000 types with CSharpCodeProvider

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TEST_WITH_COMPILATION()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        builder.Append("using System;\n");      
        builder.Append("namespace MyDynamicAssembly\n");
        builder.Append("{\n");


        for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
        {
            builder.Append(@"   
public class MyType"+i+ @"
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}");
        }          

        builder.Append("\n}");


        CompilerResults results = new CSharpCodeProvider().CompileAssemblyFromSource(new CompilerParameters
        {
            GenerateInMemory = true,
            GenerateExecutable = false,
        }, builder.ToString());                     

        var types = results.CompiledAssembly.GetTypes();

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed, " Compiled");
    }
```

This is the code that allows me to create 4000 types with Emit

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TEST_WITH_EMIT()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();            

        ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = AppDomain
         .CurrentDomain
         .DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("MyDynamicAssembly"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run)
         .DefineDynamicModule("MyModule");

        List<Type> types = new List<Type>();

        for (int i=0; i < limit; i++)
        {
            TypeBuilder typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType("MyType" + i, TypeAttributes.Public);
            typeBuilder.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public);               
            CreateAutoImplementedProperty(typeBuilder, "ID", typeof(int));
            CreateAutoImplementedProperty(typeBuilder, "Name", typeof(string));
            types.Add(typeBuilder.CreateType());
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed, " Emitted");       

    }
```

Source code for CreateAutoImplementedProperty :

```
    public static void CreateAutoImplementedProperty(TypeBuilder builder, string propertyName, Type propertyType)
    {
        const string PrivateFieldPrefix = "m_";
        const string GetterPrefix = "get_";
        const string SetterPrefix = "set_";

        FieldBuilder fieldBuilder = builder.DefineField(
            string.Concat(PrivateFieldPrefix, propertyName),
                          propertyType, FieldAttributes.Private);

        PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder = builder.DefineProperty(
            propertyName, PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, propertyType, null);

        MethodAttributes propertyMethodAttributes =
            MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName |
            MethodAttributes.HideBySig;

        MethodBuilder getterMethod = builder.DefineMethod(
            string.Concat(GetterPrefix, propertyName),
            propertyMethodAttributes, propertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);

        ILGenerator getterILCode = getterMethod.GetILGenerator();
        getterILCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        getterILCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder);
        getterILCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        MethodBuilder setterMethod = builder.DefineMethod(
            string.Concat(SetterPrefix, propertyName),
            propertyMethodAttributes, null, new Type[] { propertyType });

        ILGenerator setterILCode = setterMethod.GetILGenerator();
        setterILCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        setterILCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        setterILCode.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder);
        setterILCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getterMethod);
        propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(setterMethod);
    }
```

Here are the results :

- Compiled: 00:00:00.8716579
- Emitted: 00:00:09.6288015

How could one explain the performance gap?

Comment: Anyway, `TEST_WITH_EMIT()` has a lot more work to do that an optimized compiler has to do based on a small piece of code, so I don't find it that strange that there is such a huge gap.

Comment: TEST_WITH_COMPILATION() generates a 1MB source file.

Comment: Try [benchmark.net](http://benchmarkdotnet.org/) with analyzers. For starters, it may give you some nice insights about the amount of garbage collection going on in the second approach. (It will also eliminate other potentially silly stuff like running the code under a debugger.) Note also that what you're testing here is not representative of any real-world scenario, which skews things a bit. If you really needed 4000 types with two trivial properties, for example, there'd almost certainly be a better solution to the overall problem.